# flex 3.5: how to scroll at the end of the <mx:list>?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I use flex3.5 and I have a

```
<mx:List id="globalchat_txt" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" variableRowHeight="true"  dataProvider="{messages}" itemRenderer="chat.MessageChat">
```

I add some items to messages.

```
    var message:Message = new Message(txt);
globalchat_txt.validateNow();
messages.addItem(message);
globalchat_txt.scrollToIndex(messages.length+1);
globalchat_txt.verticalScrollPosition = 99999;
globalchat_txt.validateNow();
```

I cannot make the list scroll to the last position !
it goes to last position, but there is alsways like 10-15pixels missing !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with `List` (both spark and mx) in Flex.

It can be solved by the following method (suggested by [flexponential](http://flexponential.com/2011/02/13/scrolling-to-the-bottom-of-a-spark-list/)):

```
public static function scrollToBottom(list:List):void {
    // update the verticalScrollPosition to the end of the List
    // virtual layout may require us to validate a few times
    var delta:Number = 0;
    var count:int = 0;

    while (count++ < 10) {
        list.validateNow();
        delta = list.layout.getVerticalScrollPositionDelta(NavigationUnit.END);
        list.layout.verticalScrollPosition += delta;

        if (delta == 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

I've also reported this problem as [bug #33660 for Apache Flex](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33660) some time ago...

Answer (score 1):

We also encountered this problem. try this, extend the list and override scrollToIndex function（FLEX SDK3.5）

```
override public function scrollToIndex(index:int):Boolean
    {
        // when index=-1, do nothing
        if (index == -1)
            return false;

        var success:Boolean = super.scrollToIndex(index);
        if (success)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // if doesn't show complete, immediately scroll down
        var item:ListRowInfo = rowInfo[index - verticalScrollPosition];
        if (item.height + item.y > height)
        {
            verticalScrollPosition += 1;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```